# Ionic - Disable scroll in Slides

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, scroll

I am using [ion-slides](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/) for representing images in my app.

In some cases `<ion-slides>` can contain only a single image. In that case I want to disable the horizontal scrolling of the slides. In other words, I want the image to be fixed to the screen and have no "bounce-like effects".

Can someone provide any solution to this matter?

Answer (score -1):

> lockSwipes(shouldLockSwipes) Lock or unlock the ability to slide to
>   change slides.
>
> If set to true user can not swipe in either direction on slide. False allows swiping in 
>   both directions.
>   https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#lockSwipes

You either know how many images have loaded beforehand and can set this accordingly or you need to check length possibly after the ngAfterViewInit() event fired.

[Ionic 3 Angular component load listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46332196/ionic-3-angular-component-load-listener)
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/slides/Slides/#length

Comment: I think your solution will only help lock it to slide to the next slide. It won't prevent rubberband effect on swipe to the left side.

Answer (score -1):

I think to completely "block" swipe you should do a trick using ["pointer-events" css property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events)

In your template use binding to set rule returning 'none' or 'auto' depending on the length of your array:

```
  <ion-slides [style.pointer-events]="slides.length>1?'auto':'none'">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slides">
      {{ slide }}
    </ion-slide>
  </ion-slides>
```

See stackblitz here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/ionic-ehmfj5
You can alter length of the array and see if it works the way you need.

If you have your code and you struggle to implement the solution here - post your code plz.

Comment: any explanation why 'minus' would be nice.